# Constraint associated type of a generic associated type

Tags: rust, associated-types

I have a type `Builder` with a Generic Associated Type (GAT) `InstanceForBuilder<'a>`.
I'd like to write a function (`build_with_42_for_bool<Builder>`) that constraints the `Builder` to only those cases where `Builder::InstanceForBuilder<'a>::InstanceProperty == bool` (for all `'a`).

I've been playing around for a while to get the syntax around this `for <'a>` right, but haven't been able to make this work.

The lifetime can't be a template argument of the function itself, because the reference only lives inside it.

Is this possible at all yet, given that GAT is an unstable feature?

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=73feb9440335e57bce4fb07bb70d00f6)

```rust
#![feature(generic_associated_types)]

// Trait definitions.

trait Builder {
    type InstanceForBuilder<'a>: Instance<'a>;

    fn build<'a>(&self, val: &'a usize) -> Self::InstanceForBuilder<'a>;
}

trait Instance<'a> {
    // Some functions will only work when the instance has some concrete associated type.
    type InstanceProperty;
}

fn build_with_42_for_bool<B: Builder>(builder: B)
where
    // TODO: What do I put here to make this work?
    for<'a> B::InstanceForBuilder<'a>: Instance<'a, InstanceProperty = bool>,
{
    builder.build(&42);
    // Do some testing here. The Instance won't be returned.
}

// Now try it out.

struct MyBuilder;
struct MyInstance<'a> {
    val: &'a usize,
}

impl Builder for MyBuilder {
    type InstanceForBuilder<'a> = MyInstance<'a>;

    fn build<'a>(&self, val: &'a usize) -> Self::InstanceForBuilder<'a> {
        MyInstance { val }
    }
}

impl<'a> Instance<'a> for MyInstance<'a> {
    type InstanceProperty = bool;
}

fn main() {
    let builder = MyBuilder;
    build_with_42_for_bool(builder); // TODO: Doesn't work
}
```

In my actual code, `build_with_42_for_bool` is a helper for testing that constructs the arguments passed to `build` in a specific way. For now I'll probably just inline that function everywhere, since the only problem is how to specify the lifetime of this one function. The code itself works fine.

Here's the full error:

```
Compiling pairwise-aligner v0.1.0 (/home/philae/git/eth/git/astar-pairwise-aligner)
error[E0271]: type mismatch resolving `for<'a> <<_ as Builder>::InstanceForBuilder<'a> as Instance<'a>>::InstanceProperty == bool`
  --> examples/test.rs:45:5
   |
45 |     build_with_42(builder); // TODO: Doesn't work
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected `bool`, found associated type
   |
   = note:         expected type `bool`
           found associated type `<<_ as Builder>::InstanceForBuilder<'_> as Instance<'_>>::InstanceProperty`
   = help: consider constraining the associated type `<<_ as Builder>::InstanceForBuilder<'_> as Instance<'_>>::InstanceProperty` to `bool`
   = note: for more information, visit https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch19-03-advanced-traits.html
note: required by a bound in `build_with_42`
  --> examples/test.rs:19:53
   |
16 | fn build_with_42<B: Builder>(builder: B)
   |    ------------- required by a bound in this
...
19 |     for<'a> B::InstanceForBuilder<'a>: Instance<'a, InstanceProperty = bool>,
   |                                                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ required by this bound in `build_with_42`

error[E0271]: type mismatch resolving `for<'a> <MyBuilder as Builder>::InstanceForBuilder<'a> == <MyBuilder as Builder>::InstanceForBuilder<'a>`
  --> examples/test.rs:45:5
   |
45 |     build_with_42(builder); // TODO: Doesn't work
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ type mismatch resolving `for<'a> <MyBuilder as Builder>::InstanceForBuilder<'a> == <MyBuilder as Builder>::InstanceForBuilder<'a>`
   |
note: expected this to be `<MyBuilder as Builder>::InstanceForBuilder<'a>`
  --> examples/test.rs:32:35
   |
32 |     type InstanceForBuilder<'a> = MyInstance<'a>;
   |                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   = note: expected associated type `<MyBuilder as Builder>::InstanceForBuilder<'a>`
                       found struct `MyInstance<'a>`
help: a method is available that returns `<MyBuilder as Builder>::InstanceForBuilder<'a>`
  --> examples/test.rs:8:5
   |
8  |     fn build<'a>(&self, val: &'a usize) -> Self::InstanceForBuilder<'a>;
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ consider calling `Builder::build`
note: required by a bound in `build_with_42`
  --> examples/test.rs:19:40
   |
16 | fn build_with_42<B: Builder>(builder: B)
   |    ------------- required by a bound in this
...
19 |     for<'a> B::InstanceForBuilder<'a>: Instance<'a, InstanceProperty = bool>,
   |                                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ required by this bound in `build_with_42`

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0271`.
error: could not compile `pairwise-aligner` due to 2 previous errors
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer from DreamConspiracy is a little outdated. I'd like to reuse the example codes from him to show a [compiled solution](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=0860c6159635aa06890c5cf64b82aa22)

Instead of

```
where B::InstanceForBuilder::InstanceProperty = bool
```

You should write

```
fn build_with_42_for_bool_instance<'a, B, I>(builder: B)
where
    B : Builder<InstanceForBuilder<'a>=I>,
    I : Instance<'a, InstanceProperty=bool>,
{
    builder.build(&42);
}
```

Comment: oh cool so simple :) Has this always worked? Or is there some recent feature enabling this?

Comment: I tried this on rustc 1.64 and it doesn't work. Because the GAT (Generic Associated Type) is just stabilized recently in rustc 1.65. Luckily, the online rust playground is equipped with this version. But this answer should work on older nightly rustc, since it avoids the "issue #20041" in the answer from @DreamConspiracy. And GAT works well on older nightly rustc.

Comment: Ah I didn't realize this uses GATs, but that makes sense

Answer (score 2):

The correct syntax to do what you want is:

```rust
where B::InstanceForBuilder::InstanceProperty = bool
```

there's no need to introduce the `for<'a>` lifetime because the value of the associated type is not allowed to depend on the lifetime parameter. If you [compile this code](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=e366b6a3a0a2ebc4b11263df9e15c9b5), you'll find that you get another error:

```
error: equality constraints are not yet supported in `where` clauses
  --> src/main.rs:19:5
   |
19 |     B::InstanceForBuilder::InstanceProperty = bool,
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ not supported
   |
   = note: see issue #20041 <https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/20041> for more information
```

There's no immediate workaround for this. If you badly need this, you may be able to write a new trait, implement it only for `bool`, and then constrain things to that trait. That will get messy quickly though.